# iTextSharp change value of the Child

Tags: c#, itext

i am currently trying for hours to change the name of the children in iTextSharp, i could also use iText 7.0, but i couldn't find there anything useful either. [Image of the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hp6e.png) Now i want to change Value1 and Value2 in my PDF with `PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs); AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;` from iTextSharp.
I already tried all build in functions in the libary out.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of children are you taking about. From your code lines I'd think you are talking about AcroForm form fields. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, i use AcroForm

Comment: And what do you want to change? In one sentence you mention the *name*, in another you mention *values*...

Comment: The names of the childs i think